# How to use map operator as mergeMap?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Now that `mergeMap` is deprecated, and the source has this comment in it:

```
/* @deprecated resultSelector no longer supported, use inner map instead */
```

How do I use an "inner map" instead? I guess that means using the `map` operator function inside of `.pipe`, but the observable is not flattened, as it is with `mergeMap`.

```
obs1$.pipe(map(() => obs2$)).subscribe(r => console.log(r === obs2$))
// > true
```

So, how do the equivalent of `mergeMap` without it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You still use mergeMap, it's just the resultSelector function that deprecates.

This one is not deprecated:

```
export function mergeMap<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<R>, concurrent?: number): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

However, these are:

```
/** @deprecated resultSelector no longer supported, use inner map instead */
export function mergeMap<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<R>, resultSelector: undefined, concurrent?: number): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
/** @deprecated resultSelector no longer supported, use inner map instead */
export function mergeMap<T, I, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<I>, resultSelector: (outerValue: T, innerValue: I, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number) => R, concurrent?: number): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

Comment: And the workaround for the depreciation of the result selector is in the migration guide: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-result-selector-migration

Comment: If anyone are looking for the migration doc that @cartant posted, it was deleted and can be found here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/661a9a3cbc184fec0ca93178a2713b1044142b1f#diff-2059af00cf2f5c11dc2744fcf996a7348169fabf1c7cfc00668db56482932611

Comment: @cartant the link doesn't work. is there another code example enywhere?

Comment: @Andresch This link should be good and shouldn't break: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/1e1e022ed9fdc4a4bfed63cf151887031ac57398/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Answer (score 0):

Here's example of doing this inner map

```
this.subj1.pipe(mergeMap((outer) => this.subj2.pipe(map((inner) => [outer, inner]))))
```